# putting tikzpicture inside beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to add tikzpicture inside Beamer. However, I cannot use such functions as `\pause`, `enumerate` etc with TikZ.

Here is what I got thus far. I would like to change the `enumerate` environment and `\pause` after each point.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.0cm, right=2.0cm, top=4.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Time Line of the Model}


\begin{tikzpicture}
 %draw horizontal line
 \draw (-2,0) -- (10,0);

 %draw vertical lines
 \foreach \x in {-1.5,3,8}
   \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);

 %draw nodes
 \draw (-1.5,0) node[above=3pt] {$ 0 $};
 \draw (3,0) node[above=3pt] {$ 1 $};
 \draw (8,0) node[above=3pt] {$ 2 $};

\small
\node[align=left, below] at (0,-.5)%
{
1) The board of directors \\ offers the manager a \\ contract ($\omega_0, \omega_p, \omega_v$).\\\\ 
2) The short-term $v_S$, \\and the long-term $v_L$  \\ projects are initiated \\ by the manager.\\\\
3) The manager is \\ (partially) compensated \\ a fixed wage of $\omega_0$.\\\\
4) The IPO price of the \\stock  $p_0$ is determined \\by the investors
};


\node[align=left, below] at (4.5,-.5)%
{
1) Speculators observe\\ costly noisy signals $\theta_S $ \\ and $\theta_L)$ of the value of \\ short- and long-term \\ project. \\\\
2) The market for the firm's \\ shares opens for trade;\\ and the resulting market \\ price is $p$.\\\\
3) The manager is \\ (partially) compensated \\ an amount of $\omega_p p$.
};


\node[align=left, below] at (8.5,-.5)%
{
1) The terminal value \\of the firm $v$ is realized.\\\\
2) The manager is \\  (partially) compensated \\an amount of $\omega_v v$.
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `columns` environment to split your page; the `tikzpicture` works well for the line across the top, but there's no need to use it for all of the other parts.

[image: screenshot]

Note that the `columns` environment takes an optional argument to specify the vertical alignment; I've used `[t]` for `top`. The environment allows you to specify each column using

```
\begin{column}{<width>}
    content
\end{column}
```

which I have done, and changed all of your manual lists to `enumerate`. You can now add `\pause` at the end of each `\item` and get the display you want :) See section 12.7 of [the documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for more details.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Time Line of the Model}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    %draw horizontal line
    \draw (-2,0) -- (10,0);

    %draw vertical lines
    \foreach \x in {-1.5,3,8}
    \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);

    %draw nodes
    \draw (-1.5,0) node[above=3pt] {$ 0 $};
    \draw (3,0) node[above=3pt] {$ 1 $};
    \draw (8,0) node[above=3pt] {$ 2 $};

\end{tikzpicture}
\small
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item The board of directors offers the manager a  contract ($\omega_0, \omega_p, \omega_v$). 
            \item The short-term $v_S$, and the long-term $v_L$   projects are initiated  by the manager.
            \item The manager is  (partially) compensated  a fixed wage of $\omega_0$.
            \item The IPO price of the stock  $p_0$ is determined by the investors
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.35\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item  Speculators observe costly noisy signals $\theta_S $  and $\theta_L)$ of the value of  short- and long-term  project. 
            \item The market for the firm's  shares opens for trade; and the resulting market  price is $p$.
            \item The manager is  (partially) compensated  an amount of $\omega_p p$.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.25\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item The terminal value of the firm $v$ is realized.
            \item  The manager is   (partially) compensated an amount of $\omega_v v$.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I understand your point, but I think the question is a little ambiguous *I would like to change the enumerate environment and \pause after each point.* Let's wait for clarification from the OP

Comment: I actually deleted my previous comment because, thinking a bit over your answer, it's clear it also provides the basics to add later on overlays in whatever manner the OP wants.

Comment: Great!! It is awesome!!!!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Elias you're welcome :) If my answer helped, don't forget to upvote it using the up arrow; if it solved the problem, please consider accepting it using the green check mark :)